# cooking for shabbat in a campfire

Tags: shabbat, cooking-bishul

Does anyone know where there is a elaborated set of `Halachot` for `Shabbat` in the outdoors. 
More precisely I would like to cook chicken on coals for `Shabbat` morning.
 My idea is to make a bonfire Friday afternoon, dig a hole before `Shabbat` and put the coals and the chicken wrapped in foil in the hole. 
I want to know what are the `Halachot` I need to be aware of.

Comment: You're looking for the laws of Hatmana B'Davar HaMosef Hevel (burying [food] in something that increases heat). This is a classic example, and is forbidden. The laws are in Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim startng in Chapter 253 and on. [Incomplete article with some more sources here: http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Hatmana ]

Comment: See Chapter 257 in the Shulchan Aruch HaRav (translation here: http://shulchanaruchharav.com/Home-Database/default.aspx?pageid=chapter_2572 )

Comment: Any halachic work from at least a couple hundred years ago would deal explicitly with these issues. They didn't have electricity

Answer (score 4):

You need to be aware of the halochos of hatmono (=insulating food), see below extracted from [dinonline](http://dinonline.org/2011/02/03/shabbos-hatmana-insulating-foods-before-and-on-shabbos/). I suggest you read the whole article and then CYLOR.

> There are two ways of insulating food:
>
> מוסיף הבל – Insulating with something that increases heat.
>
> אינו מוסיף הבל – Insulating with something that retains the heat.
>
> מוסיף הבל – Insulation that Adds Heat Burning ash was the most
>   commonly used item to insulate food. Chazal forbade this type of
>   insulation out of concern that one may come to stoke the ashes which
>   have in them burning coals to keep them alight for longer  Anything
>   that positively adds heat was included in the prohibition and may not
>    be used for insulating purposes. Since the concern is that one may
>   come to stoke these materials at any moment (not just prior to the
>   insulation), the concern applies as long as they are being used. Thus,
>   a pot may not be insulated with these materials even before Shabbos.
>
> אינו מוסיף הבל If one were to insulate a pot on Shabbos with something
>   that does not add heat, but retains the heat, he may notice before
>   doing the hatmana that the food is not as hot as he wishes it to be,
>   and Chazal were concerned that he may come to heat it up on Shabbos,
>   thus transgressing the melacha of cooking. Since the concern is that
>   one may come to heat up the pot of food prior to its insulation, the
>   concern is only applicable on Shabbos itself. However, when done
>   before Shabbos there is no room for concern since then he is permitted
>   to heat up the pot before insulating it since it is not yet Shabbos.
>   Therefore, on Erev Shabbos, a pot may be insulated with towels or
>   blankets to keep it warm
>
> Practical Cases
>
> In order for hatmana to be forbidden, four conditions must be present:
>
> הטמנה לגמרי – it must be fully wrapped,
>
> בכלי ראשון – the food must be in its original pot,
>
> כוונה – one must have intention to insulate it,
>
> נוגע בקדירה – the covering/wrapping must touch the pot/food.
>
> If ALL of the above conditions are present, it is considered hatmana
>   and it is forbidden. However, if even ONE of the above conditions is
>   missing, it is not considered hatmana and may be done even on Shabbos.